# GNU Screen: using VT100 ASCII codes

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, keymap, ascii, vt100

I try to move with the VT100 keys [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) in GNU Screen:

```
$ screen
$ hello <left><left> ESC C ESC D
```

but "ESC D" deletes until the end of line and ESC C does nothing. Perhaps, I am not using right VT100 emulation. How can I test it and how can I get the ASCII codes working from commandline with Screen?

Answer (score 0):

The VT100 escape code for Left and Right are actually Escape [ (optional number) D / C respectively.

Based upon your shell, ESC D will be translated to Alt/Meta-D which for Bash (assuming you're using a default shell) will delete to end of line.  ESC C will be translated as Meta/Alt-C which goes to end of line.  Neither of these bindings have anything to do with VT100 codes.